# Spring @ControllerAdvise stopped working some time after deployment to AWS EB

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services

I have the following code deployed to AWS elastic beanstalk:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class FooControllerAdvice {

    @ExceptionHandler(value = NotFoundException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<RestError> handleNotFound(HttpServletRequest req, NotFoundException ex) {

        RestError restError = ...

        return new ResponseEntity<>(restError, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }
}
```

After deployment, the `NotFoundException` is caught by `handleNotFound` correctly and it returns 404 as expected. However, after some time (about one hour), it will no longer be caught by `handleNotFound` and it starts returning 500 instead. I'm not sure whether it is AWS EB issue or Spring issue. Anyone has faced similar issue before? Please advise, thanks!

Update:

After further investigation, I suspect it happened after hourly AWS EB log rotation.

The first log starting from 10 am which contributes to 404:

```
2017-10-23_10:03:14.957 [qtp739973450-13] DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver.resolveException - Resolving exception from handler ...
2017-10-23_10:03:14.958 [qtp739973450-13] DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver.doResolveHandlerMethodException - Invoking @ExceptionHandler method: ...
```

The next log starting from 11 am which contributes to 500:

```
2017-10-23_11:45:38.990 [qtp739973450-14] DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver.resolveException - Resolving exception from handler ...
2017-10-23_11:45:38.990 [qtp739973450-14] DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.a.ResponseStatusExceptionResolver.resolveException - Resolving exception from handler ...
2017-10-23_11:45:38.991 [qtp739973450-14] DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver.resolveException - Resolving exception from handler ...
```

It looks like the second one did not manage to find `@ExceptionHandler` method and used the default instead.

Update:

Today I had another strange behaviour. There's another method in the same class returning 409 response like below:

```
@ExceptionHandler(value = DataExistsException.class)
public ResponseEntity<RestError> handleDataExists(HttpServletRequest req, DataExistsException ex) {

    RestError restError = ...

    return new ResponseEntity<>(restError, HttpStatus.CONFLICT);
}
```

Some time after deployment, this one starts to give 500 instead of 409 (Spring cannot find this `ExceptionHandler`). At the same time, `handleNotFound` is still returning 404 correctly...

Comment: Can you provide any logs, stacktrace?

Comment: @Leffchik The stack trace is just from the `NotFoundException` since it was no longer caught by `@ControllerAdvice`. I am trying to find if anything caused the change from 404 to 500 but there's no relevant logs so far... Please enlighten me if you have any idea on which direction I shall go with the debugging, thanks!

Comment: Change the log level of spring logs (org.springframework) to debug level and then see what's happening.

Comment: @AnkitBhatnagar I just realised I used org.springframework.web, switched it now and waiting for the change to appear. Hopefully there's something in the log. Thanks for your advice!

Comment: Looks weird.. When does your exception occurs? Somewhere in `@Controller`? During some request? R U sure that this is the same requests?

Comment: @Leffchik This is a test environment and I am just testing by firing the request that would cause the `NotFoundException`. The exception is thrown from `@Service`. This is definitely the same request because it's the only request that I am firing from postman.

Comment: I had the same problem and opened an issue here: https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-15861

Comment: Haha yup :D. I will update this answer after I test it next week. Thanks bro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that it's actually a [bug](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-15907) from Spring, fixed in 5.0 RC4.